# How can I implement a maven dependency into my nodejs code?

Tags: node.js, maven

My backend server is implemented by nodeJS.

Now, I need to add a new feature and a maven dependency is required according to the related document.

The document just says:

```
//Add dependency

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.COMPANY.A</groupId>
    <artifactId>SOME-NAME</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But my code is written in NodeJS, so I wonder how I can insert this dependency setting into my code.

Any comment or link that I can refer to is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to import Maven dependency to NodeJS code. NodeJS does not support running uncompiled Java code.

If your dependency has a Main class, you can download the Jar from [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) and run it as follows:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const output = execSync('java -cp ./SOME-NAME-1.0.0.jar com.foo.MyMainClass');
```